# Terraform destroy - an way to exclude dynamodb table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, terraform, devops

is it possible to exclude a via terraform created dynamodb table when doing `terraform destroy`?
want to avoid deleted an existing table

Comment: You can remove it from your state first. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can achieve that behavior by using a `lifecycle` block with the `prevent_destroy` meta-argument ([docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#lifecycle-lifecycle-customizations)). For instance:

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "my-dynamodb-table" {
  # configs...
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}
```

The lifecycle block is available for all `resource` blocks.

Comment: this doesn't prevent from a resource being destroyed when `terraform destroy` is executed.

Comment: a `terraform destroy` on resources with the `prevent_destroy` lifecycle fails with this error: `resource X has lifecycle.prevent_destroy set, but the plan calls for this resource to be destroyed. To avoid this error and continue with the plan, either disable lifecycle.prevent_destroy or reduce the scope of the plan using the -target flag.`